# Custom listview setOnItemClickListener not working.

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-lists

I have one custom listview and want to perform the click event on listview rows and want to get the user define class object to perform the next operations. Below is the code I have tried

```
ListView tInfoListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.tableInfoList);
tInfoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                System.out.println("Inside");
                 Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked Now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

also I have tried like this

```
tInfoListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                System.out.println("Inside");
                Object o = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                System.out.println("*********"+o);
            }
        });
```

But nothing worked. Also i have set the following properties to the textviews used on the listview row.

```
android:clickable="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

But still not worked. Please guide me and where am doing wrong.

Comment: what exact error do you get....

Comment: use android:descendantFocusability in your row layout

Comment: @MeenalSharma in parent layout or in all controls ?

Comment: use Toast.makeText(classname.this, "Clicked Now", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  instead of your code.

Comment: @IrshadKhan I have used system.out.println but nothing is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by setting those listener at the time of initialization because it seems that you are initializing your views every time the user clicks a list's row .....

Answer (score 0):

In the custom adapter, that you are using, in the getView() method, set an OnClickListener to the convertView that you are returning in the getView() method as below.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be has a focusable view in the row layout, for example, a button.

use android:descendantFocusability in your row layout